# PayPal Rest API on ASP Classic

Tags: paypal, asp-classic

I'm having a problem running the "**First REST Call**" to the PayPal API.
I've tried calling the API with cUrl with my credentials and no issue whatsoever, but when I call the REST API from ASP Classic I get the error message "*The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.*"

I tested all the permutations of statements, I tried to remove and add options, but the error message is always the same.

Here is my code:

```
 Const c_URL = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"   
 Const c_UserID = "AZxxxxxx" '// Here i put my real Client-ID
 Const c_Secret = "EBxxxxxx" '// Here I put my real Secret
 Const c_Data = "grant_type=client_credentials"

 Dim x_HTTP
 Set x_HTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")

 Call x_HTTP.Open("POST", c_URL, False)
 Call x_HTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
 Call x_HTTP.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
 Call x_HTTP.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en_US")
 Call x_HTTP.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(c_UserID + ":" + c_Secret))
 Call x_HTTP.Send(c_Data)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Open up Fiddler or a similar traffic monitoring tool and check the request made by `curl` to the request made by `ServerXmlHttp`.

Comment: Thank you @Lakymart, but I have only FTP access to the server. I'll try to run the code from a local server.

Comment: I see there is another almost [identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504148/using-paypal-rest-api-with-classic-asp) without solution.